# Access Denied Error

Tags: access-denied

I'm currently getting access denied on every .aspx page in a site collection.

I'm able to access .pdf and other documents without any issue.

I'm set as the Site Collection administrator but still get blocked with any .aspx page.

When looking at ULS I see:

```
Populating navigation children for web: /SITES/SITECOLLECTION/SUBSITE
--- --- ---
Leaving Monitored Scope (CachedArea: Caching SPQuery against against list: Pages, web: /SITES/SITECOLLECTION/SUBSITE). Execution Time=25.1021
--- --- ---
Access denied.
--- --- ---
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied., StackTrace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetFileOrFolderProperties(String strUrl, ListDocsFlags listDocsFlags, Boolean throwException, SPBasePermissions& permMask)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.PropertiesCore(Boolean throwException)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_Exists()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.ProcessSPNavigationNode(SPNavigationNode node, SPNavigationNode previousSibling, PortalSiteMapNode parentNode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode.PopulateNavigationChildren(NodeTypes includedTypes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.PopulateNavigationChildrenInner(NodeTypes includedTypes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.PopulateNavigationChildren(NodeTypes includedTypes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapNode.GetNavigationChildren(NodeTypes includedTypes, NodeTypes includedHiddenTypes, Boolean trimmingEnabled, OrderingMethod ordering, AutomaticSortingMethod method, Boolean ascending, Int32 lcid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapNode.GetNavigationChildren(NodeTypes includedTypes, NodeTypes includedHiddenTypes, OrderingMethod ordering, AutomaticSortingMethod method, Boolean ascending, Int32 lcid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapNode.GetNavigationChildren(NodeTypes includedHiddenTypes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.GetChildNodes(PortalSiteMapNode node, NodeTypes includedHiddenTypes)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.GetTreeView(String viewPath)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapDataSource.GetHierarchicalView(String viewPath)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.GetData(String viewPath)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.DataBindItem(MenuItem item)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.PerformDataBinding()    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect()    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.EnsureDataBound()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AspMenu.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)    
 at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

**Question:**
What exactly is the "Populating Navigation Children for Web" and is there a way to resolve the access denied issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I have the same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: === WARNING: Doing this is very dangerous and I only did it in my DEV environment. === I never got a full understanding of the issue but we learned a couple of things. The access denied came from a bad link. I actually went into the 15 hive and manually modified one of the files to hide the left nav, which gave me some room to move. I then removed all of the links, restored the left nav in the 15 hive file and manually added the left nav links back until it broke again.

Comment: Hi. In my environment we were able to solve it by disabling Anonymous Access and then enabling it again.
Thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: Grant the users Browse Directories permission level at the scope where you are(site/web/etc).